# How to Edit Kernel Parameters on 20.04

Tags: root, ubuntu-20.04

How to edit kernel Parameters when the files are on RO (Read Only)? i would like to change /proc/sys/fs/inode-state

```
sudoedit /proc/sys/fs/inode-state
```

getting error as below since the file in RO
unable to write to /proc/sys/fs/inode-state: Permission denied

i can edit /etc/sysctl.conf but i dont want to show in sysctl.conf

using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this  site in the [help].

Comment: /proc shows info ...... in virtual files. Please check that /proc contains no files with content: `$ du -h /proc` ....... i.e. "file content" shows up only when you read INFO with e.g. `cat /proc/[file]` or `gedit /proc/[file]`

Comment: yea Some files cannot access or Permission denied, then how do i attach patch to kernel to change Parameters?